# Remove two specific letters in php

Tags: php, joomla, trim, prefix, substr

In joomla iam using this php code to get language prefix in joomla :

$lang = substr(JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag(), 0,2)

What this code do is extract prefix languages :

es
fr
en
it

I need to add something to this code so if the extracted = en remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it in one line without a condition:

```
 $lang = str_replace('en', '', substr(JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag(), 0, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an if then else statement after it is called?

```
$lang = substr(JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag(), 0,2);
if ($lang = "en")
{
    $lang = "";
}
```